# Drop down not populating categories

Tags: wordpress, select

I just started wordperss and Im trying to fetch car models from categories into a dropdown list. 
I tried every possible example I could find but got no output.
Im putting this code into my theme's funtions.php.

My category name/slug is Model(model) and id number is 3. It has 4 sub categories under.

```
$sel = 0;

  $args = array(
                'show_option_all'    => '',
                'show_option_none'   => '',
                'orderby'            => 'ID', 
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'show_count'         => 0,
                'hide_empty'         => 1, 
                'child_of'           => 3,
                'exclude'            => '',
                'echo'               => 1,
                'selected'           => 0,
                'hierarchical'       => 0, 
                'name'               => 'cat',
                'id'                 => '',
                'class'              => 'postform',
                'depth'              => 0,
                'tab_index'          => 0,
                'taxonomy'           => 'category',

                'hide_if_empty'      => false,
                    'walker'             => ''
  );
   $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

and if I try to print $dropdown it prints blank dropdown.

Comment: I finally got the answer. All my categories are empty so I needed to change 'hide_empty' => 1 to 'hide_empty'  => 0

Answer (score 1):

If `echo` is set to `1` it will be displayed directly... If you want to return the dropdown to `$dropdown`, you have to set `echo` to `0`.

Comment: Still not working. It only gives back 'uncategorized' as list item.

Comment: Do you have added more than the default category? Note: These are categories not tags...

Comment: yes this was the only solution. Thanks. I dont know why I cant upvote ur comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
            'show_option_none'   => '',
            'orderby'            => 'ID', 
            'order'              => 'ASC',
            'show_count'         => 0,
            'hide_empty'         => 1, 
            'child_of'           => 3,
            'exclude'            => '',
            'echo'               => 0,
            'selected'           => 0,
            'hierarchical'       => 0, 
            'name'               => 'cat',
            'id'                 => '',
            'class'              => 'postform',
            'depth'              => 0,
            'tab_index'          => 0,
            'taxonomy'           => 'category',

            'hide_if_empty'      => false,
                'walker'             => ''
```

);
$categories = wp_dropdown_categories($args);
print_r($categories);

This prints the dropdown list of children of cat 3. 
Note: It prints only those cats, which are asigned to any posts.
ex: Let parent category be 'New'. It has 3 children - 'n1','n2','n3'.
If you assign a post with cat 'New', 'n1','n2', then only n1, n2 will be listed in dropdown.
Until you assign category to any post, that wont be listed in drop down.

Comment: Thanks @pranita, I changed hide_empty =>0 to show empty categories